# guardar valores de campos en una variable laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Espero me peudan ayduar a esclarecer un poco mejor lo que tengo que hacer con laravel.

Necesito tomar 3 valores que escribire en 3 campos y enviarlas a unas variables temporales en php, no necesito grabarlas en la base de datos ni nada, unicamente necesito que se guarden en estos 3 campos.

Dentro de la carpeta config, tengo un archivo que se llama variables, con lo siguiente.

```
<?php



return [


    'boolean' => [
        '0' => 'No',
        '1' => 'Si',
    ],

     'SINO' => [
        'NO' => 'NO',
        'SI' => 'SI',
    ],


    'estado' => [
        'NORMAL' => 'NORMAL',
        'NO NORMAL' => 'NO NORMAL',
    ],

];
```

y hago uso de esas variables estaticas de este modo :

```
{!! Form::mySelect('estadocita', 'Estado cita: ', config('variables.boolean')) !!}
```

Lo que necesito es crear otras variables :

```
'ejemplo' => [
            '0' => 'No',
            '1' => 'Si',
        ],
```

Pero que yo pueda almacenar datos en esas variables desde un formulario.

Alguien me puede dar una guia con un ejemplo por favor ? Se que "cacharreando" puedo hacerlo, pero no he encontrado un ejemplo que se acomode a lo que necesito para poder moldearlo y aplicarlo.

Agradezco su atención.

EDIT

Hasta el momento hice esto.

Tengo estos campos en mi vista

```
                    <
                  {!! Form::open([
                    'action' => ['CategoriesController@store'],
                    'files' => true
                        ])
                    !!}
                  <input type="" name="nombre" class="logo-lg">
                  <input type="" name="nombre2" class="logo-lg">
                  <input type="" name="nombre3" class="logo-lg">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="width:100px;">Guardar</button>
```

Y Tengo esta función:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $nombre = $request->input("nombre");
    $nombre2 = $request->input("nombre2");
    $nombre3 = $request->input("nombre3");

    echo $nombre;
    echo $nombre2;
    echo $nombre3;
```

(Y si me imprimee los valores que estoy enviando)

Pero, solo me falta poder guardar esos valores en el archivo variables que tengo guardadado en mi carpeta config.

Para poder llamar esos datos desde otras ventanas, Alguiem me puede prestar una ayuda ?